# extra null characters when sed edit the file in place which under wirting

Tags: linux, bash, sed, centos, gnu

> System: CentOS 6.5
>
> Bash Version: 4.1.2
>
> GNU sed version: 4.2.1

1.create the file which under writing:

```
$ while sleep 1; do date +ABCDEFG[%d/%b/%Y\ %H\:%M:%S]ABCDEFG;done > access_test.log 2>/dev/null &
$ tail -n 2 access_test.log
  ABCDEFG[29/Apr/2016 14:08:14]ABCDEFG
  ABCDEFG[29/Apr/2016 14:08:15]ABCDEFG
```

2.use sed to deal with it in place.

```
$ sed -c -i --follow-symlinks -e 'w /dev/stdout' -e 'd' access_test.log > foo
$ less access_test.log
  "access_test.log" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
  @^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@....<omit>
```

3.my question is:

**when sed deal with the file wihch is under writing,  it leaved lots of null（\0） characters which line it finished.**

Why is this happening? Can I avoid it?

Note from `man sed`:

```
-c, --copy

 use copy instead of rename when shuffling files in -i mode.  While this will avoid breaking links (symbolic
 or hard), the resulting editing operation is not atomic.  This is rarely the  desired  mode;  --follow-sym-
 links is usually enough, and it is both faster and more secure.
```

Comment: What is `sed -c -i --follow-symlinks -e 'w /dev/stdout' -e 'd' access_test.log > foo` supposed to do?

Comment: @fedorqui
print lines to stdout and delete it in place, so the file's inode number will not be changed by sed, and its content save to other file, its size will decrease.

Comment: What is `-c` option, my sed doesn't have it?

Comment: @anubhava i find that sed in ubuntu have no "-c", but in centos5/6, it have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when sed deal with the file which is under writing, it leaved lots of null（\0） characters which line it finished.
>
> Why ??????

It is doing so because another process (`while` loop) has same file opened in write mode and that process (`while` loop) is writing data into `access_test.log` just after the previous file pointer position. This leaves null bytes (`\0`) in the file from start of file position to current file position when `sed` deletes all the lines from this file.

> And can i avoid it ?????

Rather than redirecting with `>` you should redirect using `>>` (append mode) where every write to `access_test.log` will be done at the end of the file by moving file pointer to the end of file.

This should work:

```
while sleep 1; do date +ABCDEFG[%d/%b/%Y\ %H\:%M:%S]ABCDEFG;done >> access_test.log 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: Just wonderful, yes, it is that; the nginx log's mode is ">" or ">>" mode ? i do this is to aviod sed -USR1 signal to nginx, so can i use "sed" method to logrotate nginx ?

Comment: Yes I think you can that as well.